# Count labels for which two metrics meet criteria

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have prometheus metrics from N number of hosts, each with two different `component`s as lables:

```
my_status{host="H1", component="a"}
my_status{host="H1", component="b"}
my_status{host="H2", component="a"}
my_status{host="H2", component="b"}
...
my_status{host="HN", component="a"}
my_status{host="HN", component="b"}
```

`my_status` is an integer between 0 and 2.

I want to count how many `host`s have a `my_status` of 2 for both components.

How do I do this in Grafana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EITHER component 'a' or 'b' status == 2:

```
count(
  count by (host) (my_status{component=~"a|b"} == 2)
)
```

BOTH component 'a' and 'b' status == 2:

```
count(
  count by (host) (my_status{component="a"} == 2 and my_status{component="b"} == 2)
)
```

The inner query counts the number of `my_status` time series, where the value is `2` and the component condition is met. The result is grouped per `host`, so if you ran it you would see something like this:

```
{host="A"} 1
{host="B"} 2
{host="D"} 4
```

The outer query simply counts the number of ***values*** returned by the inner query. Since there is only one value per host, it gives you the number of hosts matching the criteria.

Comment: Thanks! I think this almost does what I want. It looks like this counts all `host`s that have `a` or `b` == 2. But I need `a` and `b` to be == 2. I can achieve this by counting only those hosts that have a result of 2 for the inner count: `count(
  count by (host) (my_status{component=~"a|b"} == 2) == 2
)`

Comment: @Nicolas yes, that should do if there can be only one `my_status{component="x"}` per host. If there will be more (say, if there will be different `job` labels), this won't give you a correct result. Instead, you can do like this for the inner query: `count by (host) (my_status{component="a"} == 2 and my_status{component="b"} == 2)`